# IPython & matplotlib config profiles and files

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Over time, I have seen IPython (and equivalently matplotlib) using two locations for config files:

`~/.ipython/profile_default/`

`~/.config/ipython/profile_default`

which is the right one? Do these packages check both?

In case it matters, I am using Anaconda on OS X and on Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We (IPython) have kind of gone back and forth on the best location for config on Linux. We used to always use `~/.ipython`, but then we switched to `~/.config/ipython`, which is the XDG-specified location (more correct, for a given value of correct), while still checking both. In IPython 2, we're switching back to `~/.ipython` by default, to make it more consistent across the different platforms we support.

However, I don't think it should have been using `~/.config` on a Mac - it should always have been `~/.ipython` there.

Answer (score 2):

As far as `matplotlib` is concerned, on OS X the config file (`matplotlibrc`) will be looked for first in the current directory, then in `~/.matplotlib`, and finally in `INSTALL/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`, where `INSTALL` is the Python `site-packages` directory. With a standard install of Python from python.org, this is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.Y/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, where `X.Y` is the version you're using, like 2.7 or 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused. When I run `matplotlib` on Linux I get: `Userwarning: Found matplotlib configuration in ~/.matplotlib/. To conform  with the XDG base standard, this configuration location has been deprecated on Linux, and the new location is now ~/.config/.matplotlib`. This is with the latest stable version of matplotlib. Is `~/.config/.matplotlib` the location where I should store my profiles **both** in OS X and Linux or just in Linux?

Comment: @user815423426 - since the message says `~/.matplotlib` has been deprecated on Linux,

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is the same for OS X?

Comment: @user815423426 - sorry, didn't get to finish writing my message. I'd leave OS X as `~/.matplotlib`, but move that directory to `~/.config` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I know mine uses

```
~/.config/ipython/profile_default
```

but it could be possible that it would check both. [This Ipython page](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html) says that it puts it in

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/
```

so I am guessing it checks both.